# Load from JSON not working. Fabric.JS

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

Here is my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

$('#btn_edit').click(function(){
var c = JSON.stringify(canvas);

  });

$('Load').click(function(){


canvas.loadFromJSON(c);

  });

  $('#add').click(function(){
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  fill: 'green'
}));

  });
```

Comment: how is it not working - details..

Comment: Load click function is not binding. use `$('#Load').click(function(){
canvas.loadFromJSON(c);  });`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `canvas.toJSON()` instead of `JSON.stringify` , since this is the fabric method to export a canvas to json.